# How can I use grep in a loop and add new line of text each time to the same file?

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep

I am trying to use grep in a loop and extract data from many files and then save them in a text file. Currently when I write

```
grep sth > test.txt
```

It writes it in the file test.txt, but when I run the same code it will not add the text to the end of the previously saved text, it overwrites it. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `>>`

`>` overwrites the data in a file whereas `>>` appends the data to the end of the file.

As you are piping that from another command you can just use

```
command | grep sth >> test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually get the data from a webpage, so I combine curl -s with grep. But I am new to this and did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: @emad1234 No problem. I've edited for clarity. You can accept my answer so that it's shown as resolved.